# Configure Growl notifications to follow active display?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, growl

I'm using multiple monitors with my computer (running OS X Lion) and Growl notifications always show up on the main display.

Is there any plugin, setting or other way to make notifications follow me to the active display? By active I mean the display where the window currently in focus is, since that's where I'm most likely looking.

Comment: great question, also keen to see as I have asked this before

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I think it'd take some work to do exactly what you ask.  I don't know what events are fired when the active window changes, if any.  You would probably need an applescript that polls to find the current window, the display it's on, and then reassigns Growl.

However, if you're running a recent osx and the latest Growl (4.x), make the icon visible in the dock, then right-click it and assign it to all displays.

Its notifications might show up everywhere then.

Answer (score 0):

1. System Preferences->Growl
2. Display Options
3. Screen: 1 (or 2 or 3 etc…) – 0 is for your primary monitor.

[Source](http://blog.yoavfarhi.com/2009/11/10/how-to-make-growl-notification-show-up-in-your-secondary-monitor/)